# Rewrite Rule to redirect to another port while changing the directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, mod-proxy

Currently, I have a rewrite rule as below.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_= [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://localhost:8082%{REQUEST_URI} [L,P]
```

In this rewrite rule, If I sent a URL that has `_escaped_fragment_=` like below,

```
http://localhost:8080/web/?_escaped_fragment_=/privacy
```

The URL is redirected to a different port(8080 to 8082) as below,

```
http://localhost:8082/web/?_escaped_fragment_=
```

What I want to do now is, to modify this rewrite rule to remove the `/web` from the URL and redirect to a new port (8080 to 8082) if the URL has `_escaped_fragment_=` in it. For an example, If my URL is as below,

```
http://localhost:8080/web/?_escaped_fragment_=/privacy
```

I want this URL to be rewritten like below URL(new URL has port 8082 and `/web` is absent in the new URL),

```
http://localhost:8082/?_escaped_fragment_=/privacy
```

What is the rewrite rule for this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `%{REQUEST_URI}` variable, you'll need to match the actual URL:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_= [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(?:web/)?(.+)$ http://localhost:8082/$1?%{QUERY_STRING} [L,P]
```